# Add index to tuples

Tags: haskell

I have a function `addIndex [1,2,3] = [(0,1),(1,2),(2,3)]` which should add an index to each pair I am having trouble implementing this. Here what I have done;

```
addIndexs :: [Int] -> [(Int,Int)]
addIndexs [] = []
addIndexs x = zip x [1..length x]
```

I am able to implement it using zip put I feel its cheating, I want to be able to implement it without using any pre build functions.

The closest I have got without using pre build function is

```
addindex x = [(i,z) | z <- x, i <-[1..length x]]
```

however this add all index to each tuples so

```
addIndex [1,2,3] = [(0,1),(1,1),(2,1),(0,2),(1,2),(2,2)...]
```

I am just a beginner.

Comment: You are almost there. The only problem is you want to compute `z <- x` and `i <- [1..length x]` not in nested way but in parallel / side by side,  which is not supported by list comprehension on default. You may enable the language pragma `ParallelListComp` and try `addindex x = [(i,z) | z <- x | i <-[1..length x]]`.

Comment: Note that you can just write `zip myList [0..]` because `zip` will automatically truncate the list to the shorter length.

Answer (score 5):

so your question is how to implement `zip`?

Depending on the way you want to deal with different length lists (Haskell just ignores if one is longer and stops at the shorters length) it's all about finding the right pattern match:

```
myZip _  []         = []
myZip [] _          = []
myZip (x:xs) (x:ys) = (x,y) : myZip xs ys
```

(try to implement this if you will)

now you can easily bring this do what you wanted (by using `[1..]` as one of the lists - you don't need the `length` the way this is working here and in the prelude)

---

**btw**: I would have be surprised if you manage to get this working with a list comprehension (at least without zip itself in there in some form)

---

#### remark

while this is a good exercise to learn about pattern-matching and recursion you will not really do this in your real-life code

you would use just what you started with

```
addIndexs xs = zip [1..] xs
```

instead - note that you don't need the first case you added - it's included ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
addIndexs :: [Int] -> [(Int,Int)]
addIndexs [] = []
addIndexs x = myZip x [1..]

myZip :: [a] -> [a] -> [(a,a)]
myZip xs []         = []
myZip [] ys         = []
myZip (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x,y) : myZip xs ys
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use the following:

```
mapWithIndex :: (Int -> a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
mapWithIndex = go 0 where
  go i f [] = ?
  go i f (x : xs) = ?
```

Now if you'd like to make this work well with GHC's list fusion optimizations, you'll need to rewrite it using `foldr` and `build`. While some aspects would have to be modified (rewrite to/from), the gist is

```
mapWithIndex f xs = build mi where
  mi c n = foldr (\x r !i -> f i x `c` r (i + 1)) n xs 0
{-# INLINE mapWithIndex #-}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple example without using the zip-function:

```
addIndexs :: [Int] -> [(Int,Int)]
addIndexs [] = []
addIndexs xs = pairs 0 xs --first element will be indexed with 0.

pairs :: Int -> [Int] -> [(Int,Int)]
pairs n [x] = [(n,x)]
pairs n (x:xs) = (n,x):pairs (n+1) xs
```

Examples of usage:

```
> addIndexes [1] 
[(0,1)]
> addIndexes [8,9,10,1]
[(0,8),(1,9),(2,10),(3,1)]
```

In most cases, I would recommend you to use existing functions as long as you understand them. It is, however, a very good practice to implement existing functions on your own!

-Superdids